# CSS Class Kentico Admin UI

Tags: css, content-management-system, kentico

I'm looking for Kentico provided CSS classes that I can use to make CMS specific CSS edits to a site that I'm building in Kentico. I'm using a position fixed layout for the header, which is overlapped in several places by Kentico's various admin panels therefore making it impossible to change the site's banner image.

**Site Edit Mode**
[image: site edit mode]

**Admin Edit Mode**
[image: admin edit mode]

I would like to add a top margin to my header container to push it down below the Kentico adminstrative UI when the site is edited from one of these two modes, but I haven't been able to find a reliable Kentico provided CSS class.

Answer (score 1):

As Brendon said you can look ans inspect into which element giving issue making it impossible to add header in edit/live mode.

Add .EditMode before css elements and push it down the page in you own CSS like this.

```
.EditMode .my-page {
    top: 110px;
}
```

For making any size/width/position related to changes to Kentico Native controls like EditableImage, EditableRegion etc you can make changes in CSS in following files in Web solution.

bootstrap.css
bootstrap-additional.css

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific list of classes published that I'm aware of.  Best option is to right click and inspect the elements you're having issues and inspect up higher in the hierarchy of the elements to find what you're looking for.